# iOS 6/7 deltas make background container disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7, xcode-storyboard

I'm currently working on a legacy application that was initially developed before iOS 6 was out, let alone iOS 7. Part of my job is making it look acceptable on both iOS 7 and older versions. This is how my app looks in iOS 7, which is pretty much how it's supposed to look:

[image: iOS 7 screenshot]

First off: my root element is a normal view which just fills the screen, as normal. Inside it are, in order, the ScrollView containing the image and both purple bars which are Views with Labels in them.

What I did to make it work on iOS 6 and below is this:

- I added a -20 height delta to the topmost purple bar.
- I added -20 Y deltas to the ScrollView and the bottom purple bar, and of course to the labels in the top bar.

However, this is what happens:

[image: iOS 6 screenshot]

Now, first of all, the different languages have no bearing on the problem, it's just how my physical testing device is set up. The storyboards are set up the same.

What I derive from this is that the elements are positioned where they need to be as their children are all showing up in the correct spots, but the background color for the Views seems to turn transparent.

Some useful things to know:

- If I didn't mention above that I set a height, width, X or Y delta, then it is set to 0.
- All positioning is stored into the storyboard. The ScrollView has an X, Y, width and height of 0, 40, 320, 420 respectively. The top bar is at 0, 0, 320, 40 and the bottom view at 0, 460, 320, 20.
- The buttons you see to the sides and the logo at the bottom are put in programmatically. Their parent is the main view, so they're on the same level of hierarchy as the ScrollView and the two bars.
- Even if I programmatically set the background color to red (for instance) it stays invisible in iOS 6. It turns red just fine in iOS 7, so the code I use for that is fine.

Does anyone know what may be causing my backgrounds to disappear?

Comment: What are the tab bars frames in window coordinates? What happens when you set UIView.layer.borderWidth and borderColor for the bar views, can you see the borders on screen? What is the value of backgroundColor for the bars when you dump then when the views are on screen?

Comment: Yes, as yurish said it would help if you could output the frames of top and bottom bars when running on iOS6

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Adding borders visibly changes nothing. The color seems to be set correctly as well, it prints as `UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.215686 0 0 0.439216 1`. What did surprise me is the values of the height. The X, Y and width are all fine, but the height for both is 0. I'm 100% sure that nothing else is setting anything in these bars from my code, so I must have done something wrong on the storyboard. Am I wrong to add a height delta of -20 to the top bar and a Y delta of -20 to the bottom one?

Comment: You can just try to remove the delta. Truly say I do not know why do you add the delta it depends on your project. In iOS 7 toolbars may stick to the status bar edge and span its background under the status bar. They have normal hight. But you use regular UIView. Is it placed under the status bar? Does it adapt some protocols?

Comment: I need the deltas because otherwise the title bar is too big (20 pixels of empty purple below the status bar) and the bottom bar is simply not visible because it is 20 pixels high and therefor moving out of view. To solve my problem, I have for now simply added a line in code that changes the height of the two views to whatever is relevant and this works fine for now. If there are any better solutions, I'd be happy to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to viewDidLoad

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) { // if iOS 7
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone; 
    }
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't fix anything for the iOS 6 problem I'm having while at the same time breaking the iOS 7 layout (which was working fine before). Looking at the code I'm not surprised, but I thought I'd try it anyway. Thanks for trying to help though.